# Object argument becomes nested after being passed to constructor in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, nested-object, object-destructuring

I'm having trouble understanding a very weird bug while doing Part 2 on [Full Stack Open](https://fullstackopen.com/en/).
In few words: passing an object to the component turns the object into a nested object.
Namely:

```
entries.map(entry => { console.log(entry); return <PhonebookEntry  props={entry} />})
```

on `App.js` and

```
function PhonebookEntry(props) {
  console.log(props)
  //rest of code
}
```

on `index.js` don't work as expected.

When ran, the browser's console displays the following:

```
Object { name: "Derp", surname: "Derpington", phone: "012345", address: "2012 Street" }
App.js:33

Object { props: {…} }
props: Object { name: "Derp", surname: "Derpington", phone: "012345", … }
<prototype>: Object { … }
PhonebookEntry.js:2
```

Here's `App.js`:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import PhonebookEntry from './PhonebookEntry.js'

export default function App() {

  function handleAddEntry(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setEntries(entries.concat({
      name: newName,
      surname: newSurname,
      phone: newPhone,
      address: newAddress
    }))
  }

  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([
    {
      name: "Derp",
      surname: "Derpington",
      phone: "012345",
      address: "2012 Street"
    }
  ])
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [newSurname, setNewSurname] = useState('')
  const [newPhone, setNewPhone] = useState('')
  const [newAddress, setNewAddress] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Phonebook</h1>
      <ul>
        {entries.map(entry => { console.log(entry); return <PhonebookEntry  props={entry} />})}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddEntry}>
        Name: <input value={newName} onChange={(e) => setNewName(e.target.value) }/><br></br>
        Surname: <input value={newSurname} onChange={(e) => setNewSurname(e.target.value)}/><br></br>
        Phone: <input value={newPhone} onChange={(e) => setNewPhone(e.target.value)}/><br></br>
        Address: <input value={newAddress} onChange={(e) => setNewAddress(e.target.value)}/><br></br>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
  }
```

and here's `PhonebookEntry.js`:

```
function PhonebookEntry(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
      <li>
        <div>
          Name: {`${props.surname}, ${props.name}`}
        </div>
        <div>
          Phone: {props.phone}
        </div>
        <div>
          Address: {props.address}
        </div>
      </li>
    )
}

export default PhonebookEntry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not a bug, it’s a feature.

You can think of this:

```
<Component foo={bar} />
```

As this:

```
Component({ foo: bar })
```

Now, it’s a bit more complicated than just that, but really that’s what props in JSX represent.

So, just like how we have spread parameters/arguments, we also have spread props:

```
<PhonebookEntry {...entry} />
```

This is the same thing as (roughly):

```
PhonebookEntry({ ...entry })
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Back to your original example,

```
<PhonebookEntry props={entry} />
```

Would just be

```
PhonebookEntry({ props: entry })
```

Which is why it’s nested.

Comment: My concern is more why it happens rather than how to circumvent it.