# How to fix: type '{ source: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This has to be a simple fix, but I can't find anything explaining how you resolve this issue. I'm using Next.js and Typescript to make a component display an image and use hooks to modify said image. The problem is, when I pass in a string to the parameter that is typed as string, I get this error: `Type '{ source: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

Given this component:

```js
const ImageToggleOnMouseOver = (source: string) : JSX.Element => { ... }
```

When I try to use it, like so, I get the above error:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <ImageToggleOnMouseOver source='/heads_up.jpg' />
  </div>
);
```

When provided as `source: any` it works fine, but shouldn't string also work since I'm expecting to pass in a string after all?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71441739/18244921) explains how JSX props work (excluding the irrelevant details of React internals)

Comment: I think you just have to write either `(props)` (the param name should not matter) which are of type any and use `props.source` or use `({source: string})` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the declaration in the component. It is trying to assign the props object of `{ source: string }` to a parameter declared as `(source: string)`. You need to change the function definition to this:

```js
const ImageToggleOnMouseOver = ({source}: {source: string}) : JSX.Element => { ... }
```

By unpacking the `props` object and retrieving the `source` prop, you are able to specify the properties that you need in the function, and you are specifying the type of `props`.

Answer (score 1):

right type of the component should be

```js
const ImageToggleOnMouseOver = ({source} :{source: string}) : JSX.Element => { ... }
```

Comment: Could you explain more on why that is, please?